# selecting element in scrapy frame

Tags: css, xpath, scrapy, css-selectors

I am selecting elements in scrapy framework using shell. I have used `xpath` for selecting elements but I want this to be done using `response.css`. Below is the code I am using for `xpath`.

```
//div[@class="topic-hero"]//div/text()
```

I need the alternative in the form of `response.css`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no CSS selector equivalent for the XPath `text()` node-test, so your XPath `//div[@class="topic-hero"]//div/text()` has no exact translation in CSS.

You might use the CSS selector `div.topic-hero div` which is the equivalent of the XPath `//div[@class="topic-hero"]//div` which will select the entire `<div>` element.

e.g.

```
<div class="topic-hero">
   <div>foo<span>bar</span></div>
</div>
```

The XPath `//div[@class="topic-hero"]//div/text()` refers to the text node `foo`, whereas the XPath `//div[@class="topic-hero"]//div` and the CSS selector `div.topic-hero div` both refer to the `div` element `<div>foo<span>bar</span></div>`

Comment: I was struck at `div.topic-hero div`. To extract text from the `div` elements, i used `response.css('div.topic-hero div::text').getall()` which eventually does the same and i found my answer.

Comment: I was surprised to see that `::text` selector but I see it's a Scrapy CSS extension and not standard CSS